# Quartz Scheduler in one web app impacts quartz scheduler in another web app

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have two applications running on JBoss 4.3, each containing a quartz scheduler doing its own job. I have noticed that if one application is re-deployed, the quartz scheduler in the other application stops running.
I would like to know if I am using an incorrect approach

Below is the code sample used in the scheduler classes. The methods of this class are called by a Servlet Context Listener class.

```
public void startScheduler() {      
    JobDetail jobDetail = null;
    SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = null;

    schFac = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    try {
        scheduler = schFac.getScheduler();

        jobDetail = new JobDetail("resizer_job1", "resizer_group1", resizerJob.class);
        simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("resizer_scheduler1", "resizer_scheduler_group1");

        simpleTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(360000); // -- 2 hrs
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger);

        scheduler.start();      
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void stopScheduler() {

    if(scheduler != null) {
        try {
            scheduler.deleteJob("resizer_job1", "resizer_group1");              
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I would highly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: ServletContext Listener runs on web application start-up and shut-down.So how you configure the listener.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was calling the "startScheduler" method above in the "contextInitialized" method and "stopScheduler" method above in the "contextDestroyed" method of the class that extended the ServletContextListener.

Comment: There will be only one ServletContext for each web application. ServletContext will be created while deploying the application. Once the ServletContext is created, it will be used by all the servlets and JSP files in the same application. ServletContext is also called as the application scope variables in the web application scenario. So kindly check (web app configuration and schedular config) for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for the response again. The quartz scheduler needs a way to be started and I have chosen to start it when the web application containing the scheduler gets deployed. Also I have chosen to stop the scheduler when the web application is undeployed. I understand the concept of the ServletContext but what I do not understand is where you find my approach as incorrect. Please explain it in detail.

Comment: Your approach is correct. The issue i thought is ur schedular is shared between two web app. That why i mentioned maintain schedular per web app(servlet context). From your code i am unable to confirm the unique schedular per web app, So i asked you to check. Also explain how u testing.

Comment: Thanks again. We have two web applications running on jboss server and each has its own scheduler. The scheduler code is similar as shown above in both applications, except the names used in jobs and triggers. I have observed that when one of the applications is redeployed, the scheduler in the other application gets stopped. The re-deployed application's scheduler runs fine. I am not sure what is causing this issue. Please provide any suggestions.